# There is a way to use AlertDialog inside BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, bottom-sheet

i just need an Alert Dialog with title, msg and buttons, but showed as bottom sheet.

where is a way to obtain this  (without custom view)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to my question: Simply no, you're forced to use a CustomView

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using AlertDialog inside of bottomsheetdialogfragment.
Create one bottomsheetdialog which behaves like your requirement.

Please refer 
https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295
[How to use BottomSheetDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617468/how-to-use-bottomsheetdialog)

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use BottomSheetDialogFragment as you said and to set it a custom view that you wants with only title, msg and buttons

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(YourActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(YourView);

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AlertDialog` and the `BottomSheetDialog` extend `AppCompatDialog` both but have **different implementation**.
Since the layout is simple (just title, message and buttons), it is easier to use a `BottomSheetDialog` with a custom layout, rather than to use a `AlertDialog` and adapt all the behaviour and animations of the BottomSheet.

Just use the [`BottomSheetDialogFragment`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetDialogFragment.md) (which creates a `BottomSheetDialog`):

```
public class MyBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

  @Nullable @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
      @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    //Use your custom layout
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
    return view;
  }    
}
```

And then

```
MyBottomSheetDialog myBottomSheetDialog = new MyBottomSheetDialog();
myBottomSheetDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
```

Comment: but i want to use AlertDialog layout not custom

Comment: @Xan I read the question. Check the updated answer. In my opinion, or at least for my skills, it is easier to use a SheetDialog. Otherwise use an AlertDialog, and rewrite all the animations and features of the BottomSheet.